# Spinner Loader for all the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a project that contains several interfaces, and among these interfaces, there is an interface for displaying a set of statistics.

And the data for each chart is obtained through the API for each chart,

And I want to add a **spinner loader** for page.

How can I add it?

How can the problem be solved?

And through this file all statistics are displayed

```
import { Card, Col, Row, Spin } from 'antd';
import { FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../../../styles/dashboard/index.scss';
import { AuthContext, IAuthContext } from '../../../contexts/auth-context';
import colors from '../../../constants/colors';
import calendar1 from '../../../assets/icons/calendar1-icon.svg';
import waving from '../../../assets/icons/waving-hand-icon.svg';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import BarCharts from './charts/barCharts';
import PieCharts from './charts/pieCharts';
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import statisticCharts from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/Statistic';
import { ChartEntityType1, ChartEntityType2, ChartEntityType3, ChartEntityTypeAnalysis } from './types';
import schedule from "../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/Schedule";
import { MachineCategory } from '../../../constants/enums';


interface DashboardProps { }
const Dashboard: FunctionComponent<DashboardProps> = () => {

    const current = new Date();
    const date = `${current.getFullYear()}/${current.getMonth() + 1
        }/${current.getDate()}`;


    const auth = useContext<IAuthContext>(AuthContext);

    const today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    const [xytotalTopography, setxytotalTopography] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [xtopography, setXTopography] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [xyAge, setxyAge] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [xyCitytotalTopography, setxyCitytotalTopography] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [xyTopographyPercent, setxyTopographyPercent] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const [analysisCountPatient, setAnalysisCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [ctCountPatient, setCtCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [mriCountPatient, setMriCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [gammaCountPatient, setGammaCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [xrayCountPatient, setXrayCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [cesiumCountPatient, setCesiumCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [cobaltCountPatient, setCobaltCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [iodinCountPatient, setIodinCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [linacCountPatient, setLinacCountPatient] = useState<any[]>([]);


    const chartsQueryTopographyData = useQuery(['chartsQueryTopographyData'], () =>
        statisticCharts.GetTopographyStatistic({ FilterType: 1, StartDate: `${year}-01-01`, EndDate: `${year}-12-31` }),
    ).data;

    const chartsQueryCityData = useQuery(['chartsQueryCityData'], () =>
        statisticCharts.GetTopographyStatistic({ FilterType: 2, StartDate: `${year}-01-01`, EndDate: `${year}-12-31` }),
    ).data;

    const chartsQueryAgeData = useQuery(['chartsQueryAgeData'], () =>
        statisticCharts.GetTopographyStatistic({ FilterType: 3, StartDate: `${year}-01-01`, EndDate: `${year}-12-31` }),
    ).data;

    // count
    const schedulePatientCount = useQuery('schedulePatientCount', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.Analysiss,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountiodin = useQuery('schedulePatientCountiodin', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadioTherapyByIodine,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountCt = useQuery('schedulePatientCountCt', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadialImageByCT,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountGamma = useQuery('schedulePatientCountGamma', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadialImageByGamma,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountMri = useQuery('schedulePatientCountMri', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadialImageByMRI,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountXray = useQuery('schedulePatientCountXray', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadialImageByXRay,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountcesium = useQuery('schedulePatientCountcesium', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadioTherapyByCesium,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountCobalt = useQuery('schedulePatientCountCobalt', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadioTherapyByCobalt,
        }),
    ).data;

    const schedulePatientCountLinac = useQuery('schedulePatientCountLinac', () =>
        schedule.SchedulePatientCountGetAllLite({
            machineCategory: MachineCategory.RadioTherapyByLinac,
        }),
    ).data;

    // *********** this function return array of arrays
    const cleanData1 = (data: ChartEntityType1[]) =>
        data?.map((xy: ChartEntityType1) => {
            if (xy?.x !== undefined && xy?.yMale !== undefined && xy?.yFemale !== undefined) return [xy?.x, xy?.yMale, xy?.yFemale]
        });


    const cleanData2 = (data: ChartEntityType2[]) =>
        data?.map((xy: ChartEntityType2) => {
            if (xy?.x !== undefined && xy?.yTotal !== undefined) return [xy?.x, xy?.yTotal]
        });


    const cleanData3 = (data: ChartEntityType3[]) =>
        data?.map((xy: ChartEntityType3) => {
            if (xy?.x !== undefined && xy?.yPercent !== undefined) return [xy?.x, xy?.yPercent]
        });

    const cleanData4 = (data: ChartEntityTypeAnalysis[]) =>
        data?.map((xy: ChartEntityTypeAnalysis) => {
            if (xy !== undefined) if (xy?.count !== undefined && xy?.machine?.label !== undefined)
                return [xy?.machine?.label, xy?.count]
        });


    useEffect(() => {
        // x = topography, y= male, y1= female
        // *************** this return array of arrays
        const mappedData1 = cleanData1(chartsQueryTopographyData);
        const mappedData2 = cleanData2(chartsQueryTopographyData);
        const mappedData3 = cleanData2(chartsQueryAgeData);
        const mappedData4 = cleanData3(chartsQueryCityData);
        const mappedData5 = cleanData3(chartsQueryTopographyData);
        const mappedData6 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCount);

        const mappedData7 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountCt);
        const mappedData8 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountGamma);
        const mappedData9 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountMri);
        const mappedData10 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountXray);
        const mappedData11 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountCobalt);
        const mappedData12 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountcesium);
        const mappedData13 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountiodin);
        const mappedData14 = cleanData4(schedulePatientCountLinac);

        if (mappedData1) {
            setxytotalTopography([['topography', 'ذكر', 'أنثى'], ...mappedData1])
        }

        if (mappedData2) {
            setXTopography([['topography', 'المرضى المصابين'], ...mappedData2])
        }

        if (mappedData3) {
            setxyAge([['age', 'المرضى المصابين'], ...mappedData3])
        }

        if (mappedData4) {
            setxyCitytotalTopography([['', ''], ...mappedData4])
        }

        if (mappedData5) {
            setxyTopographyPercent([['', ''], ...mappedData5])
        }

        if (mappedData6) {
            setAnalysisCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData6])
        }

        if (mappedData7) {
            setCtCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData7])
        }
        if (mappedData8) {
            setGammaCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData8])
        }
        if (mappedData9) {
            setMriCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData9])
        }

        if (mappedData10) {
            setXrayCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData10])
        }

        if (mappedData11) {
            setCobaltCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData11])
        }
        if (mappedData12) {
            setCesiumCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData12])
        }
        if (mappedData13) {
            setIodinCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData13])
        }
        if (mappedData14) {
            setLinacCountPatient([['', ''], ...mappedData14])
        }
    }, [chartsQueryTopographyData, chartsQueryCityData, chartsQueryAgeData, schedulePatientCount,
        schedulePatientCountCt, schedulePatientCountGamma, schedulePatientCountMri, schedulePatientCountXray,
        schedulePatientCountCobalt, schedulePatientCountcesium, schedulePatientCountiodin, schedulePatientCountLinac]);


    return (
        <>
            <div className='dashdoard-donutData'>
                {/* welcome */}
                <Row>
                    <Card className='card-welcome'>
                        <Row className='center'>
                            <Col lg={20}>

                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                        <FormattedMessage id='welcome' />
                                        {'  '}
                                        {auth.userData?.fullName} !
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col className='mr-2 ml-2'>
                                        <img src={waving} alt='waving' />
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <small>
                                            <FormattedMessage id='follow' />
                                        </small>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Col>
                            <Col lg={4}>
                                <Row
                                    style={{
                                        color: colors.primaryColor,
                                    }}
                                    justify='end'
                                >
                                    <Col>
                                        <img
                                            src={calendar1}
                                            alt='calendar1'
                                        />
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        {' '}
                                        {'\u00a0\u00a0'}{' '}
                                        <FormattedMessage id='today' />
                                        {date}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Card>
                </Row>

                {/* Close Date Appointment*/}
                {/* <ClosestFreeAppointment /> */}

                {/* Bar Charts */}
                {/* <BarCharts topographyData={chartsQueryTopographyData?.data} ageData={chartsQueryAgeData?.data} year={year} /> */}
                <BarCharts xytotalTopography={xytotalTopography} xtopography={xtopography} xyAge={xyAge} />

                {/* Pie Charts */}
                <PieCharts xyCitytotalTopography={xyCitytotalTopography}
                    xyTopographyPercent={xyTopographyPercent}
                    analysisCountPatient={analysisCountPatient}
                    ctCountPatient={ctCountPatient}
                    mriCountPatient={mriCountPatient}
                    gammaCountPatient={gammaCountPatient}
                    xrayCountPatient={xrayCountPatient}
                    cesiumCountPatient={cesiumCountPatient}
                    cobaltCountPatient={cobaltCountPatient}
                    iodinCountPatient={iodinCountPatient}
                    linacCountPatient={linacCountPatient}
                    year={year} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using `react-query`'s `useQuery` hook.
You can simply use its' `isLoading` property.

```js
const { isLoading: isLoadingTopography, data: topoGraphyData }= useQuery(['chartsQueryTopographyData'], () =>
        statisticCharts.GetTopographyStatistic({ FilterType: 1, StartDate: `${year}-01-01`, EndDate: `${year}-12-31` }));

const {isLoading: isLoadingCity, data: cityData} = useQuery(['chartsQueryCityData'], () =>
        statisticCharts.GetTopographyStatistic({ FilterType: 2, StartDate: `${year}-01-01`, EndDate: `${year}-12-31` }));
```

then in your JSX

```
{
   isLoadingCity ? <p> Loading city chart </p> : <CityChart data={cityData}/>
}

{
   isLoadingTopography ? <p> Loading topography chart </p> : <TopographyChart data={topographyData}/>
}
```

Comment: @HibaYoussef I've made a typo. It is ```isLoading```

Comment: when i do this way, it take time about 2 second between loading and display data, how can i solve the problem?

Comment: @HibaYoussef I think its nothing to do with frontend. Your backend takes 2 seconds to respond to your request. Or maybe your internet connection is slow. But looking at your code you can split your ```PieCharts``` component into multiple component and use ```useQuery``` hook inside each components. This way, you can see some of  your charts while other one is loading.

Answer (score 0):

`useQuery()` returns a boolean called `isLoading`. You could use this boolean as a condition to render either the spinner or the chart.

If you need to wait for multiple queries to respond before rendering the UI, then I'd suggest using react-querys `useQueries()` hook with an array of all the queries you need to wait on. Then you can map an array of `status` (a string returned for each query) from those queries and derive the overall status from the collective. This will allow you to derive a loading state, an error state, and a successful state for multiple queries.

Comment: can u make example for this way?